# could it be possible to load irregular map tiles for custom tile grids

Tags: openlayers, tile

W're researching irregular vector tile loading strategy to test whether vector density in each tile makes difference to whole map loading. However, we encountered difficulties when rendering irregular vector tiles using opnelayers, with WFS source loading function not quite fitting. Could it be possible to load irregular map tiles for custom tile grids, thanks a lot?

Effect of expression as follows:
http://dimensionaledge.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/quadgrid.gif

Asked same question in Openlayer Git issues list.https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/6057